# Debian installation media with non-free packages?

Tags: debian, drivers, distribution-media

Are there any Debian DVDs (Lenny, 5.0) out there that include the non-free hardware driver components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean non-free firmware? If so, I found a link to some images here:

http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/debian-installer/

Answer (score 5):

Here's the policy from [Debian - Non Free Software](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#nonfree):

> **Where is the CD image with non-free?**
>
> Debian has a quite strict view with
>   regard to the licenses of software:
>   Only software that is Free in the
>   sense of the Debian Free Software
>   Guidelines is allowed into the actual
>   distribution. All the other, non-free
>   software (for example, software for
>   which source code is not available) is
>   not supported officially.
>
> The official CDs may freely be used,
>   copied and sold by anyone anywhere in
>   the world. Packages of the non-free
>   category have restrictions that
>   conflict with this, so these packages
>   are not placed on the official CDs.
>
> Sometimes, someone is kind enough to
>   create unofficial non-free CDs. If you
>   cannot find any links on this website,
>   you can try asking on the debian-cd
>   mailing list.

[Mailing List FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#mailing-list)